# Page cannot load CSS definition for ID html element until F12 Developer Tool opened once

Tags: asp.net, css-selectors, ie11-developer-tools

I met a problem with my website. I developed my site by ASP .NET. I met _doPostBack problem when using IE10-11 then I fixed it by installing hotfix KB's [hotfix .net _dopostback](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx). Now I met another issue with CSS definition for ID html element.

The website could load the CSS file successful but the definition for ID html element could not be loaded. Just CLASS definitions was loaded.

And after I opened F12 Developer Tool once, it will be OK.

Waiting for your helps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565627(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I try to use CLASS declaration instead of ID CSS. It would work fine.